# Redirect a subdomain to a directory, but without changing the url

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have the structure on the server:

```
customer.site.com
system/
```

The .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond% {HTTP_HOST} ^ client.site.com $ [OR]
RewriteCond% {HTTP_HOST} ^ www.client.site.com $
RewriteRule ^ (. *) $ www.site.com/system/$1?customer=customer [P]
```

The goal is to display the contents of the directory www.site.com.br/system/, inside client.site.com.br, but without changing the url, but it is not working.

Comment: What are `DocumentRoot` values for `client.site.com.br` and `www.site.com` ?

Comment: Hello anubhava. I don't have much experience with htaccess. Would you help me? Sorry my english, I'm using Google Translate.

Comment: You can try changing the `DocumentRoot` directory of `www.site.com.br` to `/path/system/`. This way you won't need to type 'system' in the URL. You need to make this change in the Apache VirtualHost directive of your domain.

Comment: Hello RoseHosting. I changed to `RewriteRule ^ (.*) $/httpdocs/system/?$1?Customer=customer[P]` and also `RewriteRule ^ (.*) $/Httpdocs/system/?$1? Customer=customer[QSA,P] `, I tried this way too` RewriteRule ^ (.*) $/system/?$1?customer=customer[P] `and also` RewriteRule ^ (.*) $/system/?$1?customer = customer[QSA,P] `but gave the 400 Bad Request error.

Comment: Can you post `VirtualHost` config for `client.site.com.br` and `www.site.com` ?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need .htaccess at all, avoid using it if possible.

To reverse proxy

In virtualhost for "client.site.com.br" just use ProxyPass:

```
ProxyPass / https://www.site.com.br/system/
ProxyPassReverse / https://www.site.com.br/system/
```

The equivalente inside .htaccess (if you so insist):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.site.com.br/system/$1 [P,L]
```